# Isn't personal-preference a meta-tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta-tags

There appears to be no case to have a post that only has the [personal-preference](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-preference) tag, since it's completely unclear what that would be about (apart from a personal preference regarding something). It's like the weak version of *subjective*.

Also, given that Programmers.SE is about subjective stuff anyway, it's also a little redundant. For example, you may as well ask: "What's the best setup for a three monitor workstation to do software development?" It's not like you'd expect anyone to give an objectively verifiable definitive answer.

My proposal then is to remove the [personal-preference](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-preference) tag from all posts that have it and ban it if possible.

Comment: Indeed, it should be blacklisted, but that'll require Stack Exchange, Inc.

Comment: That tag is a red flag, like `[polls]` on Stack Overflow. Some of those questions look OK but others look like candidates for closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree; this tag has been burninated.

[image: this tag has been BURNINATED]